# Can a losing algo strategy be good if it was winning for 1000 trades?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

My algo, in back test, runs for 1000 trades and makes a 10% profit (over a few weeks of candles), from research it seems 1000 trades is statistically significant. Obvs not all 1000 trades were winners but overall it was in profit due to the big winners. After about 1000 trades it starts losing. Were I to evaluate success based on final account balance at 1100 trades ,the test would be a failure, it would have lost 5% of the initial balance. But, if this algo was in production and I stopped it running after 1000 trades, I would be pleased with the 10% profit.

I notice that the start datetime for my backtest is important regarding profit levels reached. Clearly there are some conditions that suit the algorithm, I have not managed to program into a successful filter yet. I suspect it is trending conditions that are more favourable, and periods of ranging choppiness lead to big losses. It is a work in progress to work out how to know when to turn off the algorithm, programmatically. I guess I could look at a drawdown floor, beyond which I bail out.

But the main question is, could there be metrics that would show the algorithm favourably, since 90% of the backtest it was in profit, even though in the final stretch it lost all the profits. Which metrics should I be looking at? The WinRate was always 0.4 or above, Expectancy was always positive. If I calculate Sharpe Ratio and it is positive..are these three enough to say the algorithm is worth investigation, can I exclude the final balance in my consideration since there is maybe an element of luck as to where I stop the backtest? In other words, if the WinRate, Expectancy and Sharpe Ratio are all decent over 1000 trades, then can I ignore the final balance being a loss and assume that the algo is solid and would have got back into profit had I left it run long enough.

Comment: This sounds like overfitting.

Comment: What's the theme of your strategy? momentum? mean-reversion? What's the market correlation and how did the broad market perform in your backtest period?

Comment: It’s a trend following strategy I guess. I will baseline it against the broader market, that’s an idea- thanks.

Comment: This reminds me of martingale betting. You see your ability to lose but reason your way out of that by saying that you’ll make up that loss eventually.

Comment: I found bugs in the backtest, fixed and now i'm seeing a better equity curve. Thanks for the inputs! No way would i put any money into this until i have much much more confidence in the backtest. Quite a lot of code in there to simulate the real trading env, and of course that brings bugs with it. I am still thinking to simplify the backtest and focus on the forward test.